# Asus monitor does not get HDMI signal after "Starting Windows" screen

Tags: display, hdmi, signal

I have an Asus 247H monitor which I hooked up to a Gigabyte motherboard's (GA-Z77-D3H) on-board VGA port at first. Soon after I got my hands on an HDMI cable, I tried to replace the VGA one with it. The monitor displays HDMI picture fine from boot-up (BIOS messages/settings) up until Windows 7 loads. After the "Starting Windows" screen the monitor complains "HDMI no signal". I tried unplugging/replugging cables, reinstalling drivers (Intel Graphics HD 4000), but to no avail. Can anyone shed some light on this?

- Strangely the HDMI cable starts working every time I re-install Intel VGA driver (the "ding-dong" sound), and is recognized in the device manager and display settings. So VGA and HDMI are selectable as different monitors in the relevant dropdowns. But after I restart, everything goes back to normal... HDMI is not recognized.
- It seems to be an Intel driver problem. After uninstalling Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver, HDMI would work. As of now the newest driver from Intel (ver 15.26.12.64.2761) does not fix this.

Comment: You probably need to update your VGA drivers. Hook up the monitor using VGA port and check if the VGA drivers are up to date.

Comment: @MMRUser It works if I reinstall VGA drivers, HDMI device properly recognized. Then it's back to old state after restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problems while connecting the AOC external LCD with the dedicated Gigabyte Graphics card via HDMI. It has to be a driver issue because this is what I've found out while troubleshooting.

Symptom: In Windows 7 with HDMi my screen regularly goes blank for about 5 seconds once every 5 minutes. The same problem is duplicated in a different system with the same hardware and it still exists after my graphics card was replaced under warranty. It does not happen in Linux which indicates its root cause lies in the Windows Nvidia Graphics Driver for the card.

Troubleshooting so far: I asked on the Gigabyte online tech support and the only suggestion they had is that for appropriate HDMI "handshaking", the cables should be fully connected *before* the screen and computer are switched on (this practice however has not removed the symptom in my system).

HDMI is great for sending Video+Audio in the same cable but it's no different to DVI which is digital and pin compatible with it. So i gave up and went back to DVI. VGA is analog.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting windows in VGA mode, and dropping the resolution once in windows:

- As your machine is starting, after the BIOS but before the Windows logo, repeatedly hit the F8 key
- Select the 'VGA Mode' or 'Safe Video' mode (I forgot the exact wording)
- Check for whether or not multiple outputs are set up or expected
- reduce the screen resolution, restart as normal

Also if you have a dedicated graphics card in addition to the onboard one, check which outputs you're using.

Comment: There is a "Low Resolution Mode" which has the same issue, but "Safe Mode" works with the HDMI cable. Tried your method but didn't work :(. Strangely the HDMI cable starts working every time I re-install Intel VGA driver (the "ding-dong" sound), and is recognized in device manager and display settings. So VGA and HDMI are selectable as different monitors in the relevant dropdowns. But after I restart, everything goes back to normal... HDMI is not recognized.